# How to Reset textview to its default value?

Tags: java, android

which gets a Text with setText..  But I want to Reset the value again later.

The results I could find on the web gives me the answer to use setText("")  but this do not really resets the Text IT only does  empty the Text.

So i cant See the Default Text, declared in my xml...  So Do you habe any Idea?

Comment: did you think of saving the default value somewhere and call it back when you need it?

Comment: save the value of your textView in some variable in onCreate and use it wherever required

Comment: Yes, you need to save in in SharedPreferences.

Comment: I want to use the value from my xml where ı Set the Default value

Comment: There's simply no such thing as a default value for a TextView, what do you mean by default value?

Comment: I mean, I have Set the android:text="blablabla" i want to use blablabla as Text After i Set another Text in my activity with. Settext

Answer (score 4):

You can save your default value in the "res/values/strings.xml" like this

```
<string name="default">Your default string here</string>
```

You can use this value from xml like this:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/default"/>
```

You can use it from code too.

```
textView.setText(R.string.default);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about having a string resource as the default value?
Save it in your strings.xml file:

```
<string name="def_value">my default value</string>
```

So:

```
<TexView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/def_value" />
```

Then in your code you can reset it like so:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.myTextView);
myTextView.setText(getString(R.string.def_value));
```

Comment: +100 for this answer - all human-readable strings should be in strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

Save the default value in SharedPreferences like this:

```
    public void saveUsername(String username) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.SP_APP_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.SP_IM_USERNAME, username);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public String getUsername() {

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.SP_APP_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = sp.getString(Constants.SP_IM_USERNAME, "");

        return username;
    }

    public void resetTextView(TextView view){

        view.setText(getUsername());

    }
```

You can retrieve the default value anytime.